# maxTime is not applying in moment

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am using `moment` in my angular project. I am setting time using

```
this.when().time = moment().add(1, "days").set({hour:8,minute:0,second:0});
```

And restricting it using `minTime` and `maxTime` as below

```
this.timeOptions.minTime = this.timeOptions.maxTime = this.when().time;
```

Here minTime is applying. But, maxTime is not applying.

See the below picture:

[image]

But, somewhere else it is working fine. Help me solve this issue.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I was blindly manipulating the code somewhere else as below:

```
jQuery("#service-time").find('.dp-time-select-control-minutes .dp-time-select-control-up').removeAttr('disabled');
```

This is what caused the unexpected behavior.

Sorry for the blind question.

Thank you...